# iterate over textarea values to array values

Tags: php

I have html in textarea like this:

```
<dl>
  <dt>lorem</dt>
  <dd>
    <h1>heading</h1>
    <p>ipsum</p>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Now, I want to store them in an array:

```
$arr = explode("\n", $input);
```

And this results like this:

```
Array ( [0] =>
  <dl>
      [1] =>
         <dt>lorem</dt>
      [2] =>
         <dd>
             [3] =>
                 <h1>heading</h1>
             [4] =>
                 <p>ipsum</p>
                 [5] =>
          </dd>
          [6] =>
    </dl>
)
```

Now, how can I iterate over them to get html or text inside dt and dd?

```
$dt = '';
$dd = '';
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
  ???
}
echo $dt;
echo $dd;
```

Comment: You better be using some library for parsing DOM: https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser

Comment: any other ideas instead of using lib ?

Comment: RegExp to match text between tags and tags itself, but it's wrong way

Comment: I mean other ideas to have the data in textarea so that I can easily grab?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with that data, how you get it (human entered, generated by script, etc.) and the nature of that data itself.

Comment: Example is exactly like above. I want heading and paragraph for different group ie. in my html structure the group is dt. Its human entered...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115704/discussion-between-justinas-and-bhojendra-nepal).

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's strip tags function.

`echo (strip_tags($value));`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: This totally removes the html tags. I want html insdie dd and dt still.

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not recommend you to use *foreach* to iterate your array (you should use *while* instead), this is the solution to your question:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
     if (strpos($value, 'dt') !== false) {
          $dt = $value;
     } else if (strpos($value, 'dd') !== false) {
          $dd = $value;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you using the native PHP DOM extension in order to avoid struggling with html parsing.

http://php.net/manual/fr/book.dom.php

here is a simple example on how to do what you're looking for:

```
<?php 

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'iso-8859-1');
$dom->loadHTML($your_html_string);
$dom = $dom->getElementById($id_of_your_textarea);
foreach ($dls as $dl) {
    echo $dl->nodeValue;
}
```

it should be something like this. (not tested)

Answer (score 0):

Use the power of `DOMDocument`:

```
$html_str = '<dl>
  <dt>lorem</dt>
  <dd>
    <h1>heading</h1>
    <p>ipsum</p>
  </dd>
  <dt>lorem2</dt>
  <dd>
    <h1>heading2</h1>
    <p>ipsum2</p>
  </dd>
</dl>';

function grabTextareaDl($html_str, $type = 'text') {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html_str);
    $dl = $doc->getElementsByTagName("dl")->item(0);
    $dt = $dd = [];
    $getInnerHtml = function(DOMNode $node){
        $html = "";
        foreach ($node->childNodes as $n) {
            $html .= $node->ownerDocument->saveHTML($n);
        }
        return $html;
    };

    foreach ($dl->childNodes as $n) {
        if ($n->nodeName == 'dt' || $n->nodeName == 'dd') {
            if ($type == 'html') {                
                ${$n->nodeName}[] = $getInnerHtml($n);
            } else {
                ${$n->nodeName}[] = $n->nodeValue;
            }
        }
    }

    return ['dt' => $dt, 'dd' => $dd];
}

print_r(grabTextareaDl($html_str));
```

The output(text):

```
Array
(
    [dt] => Array
        (
            [0] => lorem
            [1] => lorem2
        )
    [dd] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
    heading
    ipsum

            [1] => 
    heading2
    ipsum2

        )
)
```

---

```
print_r(grabTextareaDl($html_str, "html"));
```

The output(html):

```
Array
(
    [dt] => Array
        (
            [0] => lorem
            [1] => lorem2
        )

    [dd] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
    <h1>heading</h1>
    <p>ipsum</p>

            [1] => 
    <h1>heading2</h1>
    <p>ipsum2</p>

        )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't want to get dt, and dd tag. I just want to get the text/html inside them.

Comment: *And I may many dd inside dl* - consider using dt and dd as arrays: `$dt = $dd = '';  .....  $dt[] = $n->nodeValue;`

Comment: yes, I have added more complex example (with multiple `dt`/`dd`) and extended my solution. Check this out